# Get the directory of a Shortcut calling a Python Script

Tags: python, directory

How does one acquire the directory of the **Windows Shortcut** calling a python script. I'd like to have multiple shortcuts in various places pointing to one script that I could edit if I wanted, but where the directory *from which* the script is called is accessible. Is this possible?

This script would likely then be compiled with py2exe or something, so if it is something that isn't possibly until THAT stage, I could go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just use a batch script instead of a shortcut.

All it needs is `python C:\path\to\script\script.py`, and the script will have the correct CWD.

The default when creating a shortcut on windows is for the `Start in:` property to be set to the folder the linked file resides in.

The script has no knowledge of the fact that it was called from a shortcut, let alone where that shortcut resides.

You can change the `Start in:` property of the shortcut to the path of the folder the shortcut resides in.

Then you can use `os.getcwd()` to get that path.

Unfortunately setting `Start in:` to `.` doesn't work.

Comment: Annoying, but works nonetheless. Is there some pythonic way, then, to create a shortcut that automatically sets the Start In property to the folder in which you want to create it?

Comment: Just use a batch file to execute the script. That way it's as if you had called script from the command line, and the script will get the correct working directory. (Added to answer)

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot obtain this information. You should use `argv` to switch behaviour of your script.

Answer (score -1):

you can do so with

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

> os.getcwd()
>
> Return a string representing the current working directory.
>   Availability: Unix, Windows.

Comment: This does not work. It prints the directory of the script itself.